# Struggling with arbitrage %

Tags: betting

Losing my mind over this basic sum of percentages that I am using to calculate arbitrage bets: there are 3 odds of the same match (1.91 + 16.50 + 10.50), their % sum is ~68,2%, so the profit amounts to ~31,8%. However, when I calculate how much (total) money should I put on each odd to get 131,8€ as a secure profit (should be 100€) using this [image: formula] it gives me ~89,5 instead of 100. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have threeway bets with odds o1, o2, and o3, then 1/o1, 1/o2, 1/o3 are the ratios in which you want to divide the bet. (One way to look at this is that you want to win the same amount either way. I will include some links with the explanations below.)

In your case you have:

- o1=1.91, o2=16.5, o3=10.5
- 1/o1=[0.5236](https://www.google.com/search?q=1/1.91), 1/o2=[0.0606](https://www.google.com/search?q=1/16.5), 1/o3=[0.9524](https://www.google.com/search?q=1/10.5)
- S=1/o1+1/o2+1/o3=[0.6821](https://www.google.com/search?q=1/1.9%2B1/16.5%2B1/10.5). From 1/S=1/0.6821=[1.4659](https://www.google.com/search?q=1/(1/1.9%2B1/16.5%2B1/10.5)) you see that you can expect the profit to be 46%.
- You have to bet b1=1/(o1*S)=[0.7675](https://www.google.com/search?q=1.4659/1.91), b2=1/(o2*S)=[0.0888](https://www.google.com/search?q=1.4659/16.5), b3=1/(o3*S)=[0.1396](https://www.google.com/search?q=1.4659/10.5).

For example if you split 100€ this way, you would get expect 46€ of profit.

| bet | odds | win |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 76.75 | 1.91 | [146.59](https://www.google.com/search?q=76.75*1.91) |
| 8.88 | 16.5 | [146.54](https://www.google.com/search?q=8.88*16.5) |
| 13.96 | 10.5 | [146.47](https://www.google.com/search?q=13.96*10.5) |

I should explicitly mention that arbitrages with such high profit margin are very very rare (at least in my experience).

In connection with the computation included in your screenshot, I will add that we both get the same value S=0.6821. The expected win is then 1/S=1.4659, i.e., you would have 46.5% profit. If you try the same computation with 146.59 instead of 131.8, you'll get amounts that add to 100 (if we ignore rounding error).

You can use rule of thumb that 1/(1-e) is approximately 1+e if e is a small number. But if you apply it to relatively big numbers (as e=0.318 in this case), the error will be much bigger.

---

Some additional links:

- Wikipedia: [Arbitrage betting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrage_betting)
- [Formula to find the right variables for risk free betting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2243689) (on Mathematics Stack Exchange)
- [How is potential profit from an arbitrage bet (a.k.a. surebet) calculated?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3163)